# How to tell if NFT is frozen without test-sending?

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, metaplex-js

simple question here, how can I tell if an NFT is frozen without test-sending?
Is there a field in the metadata, or a way I can acquire that information through metaplex? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here `@solana/spl-token`sdk needs to be used after installing the sdk you have to import `getAccount`

```
import { getAccount } from '@solana/spl-token';
```

after passing all the right parameter's this function is going to return a Account object in a promise so promises needs to be used over here to get the Account object. [image: getAccount return Type]

Once there is the Account object it's going to contain all these parameters and there is a parameter called `isFrozen` if it's true than it would mean that the token is frozen if it's false then it's not frozen.
[image]

i haven't personally used this function ever but let me know if you get any errors.